# Why is the space of trajectories for a particle a cotangent bundle?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

In Paugams book, [Towards the Mathematics of Quantum Field Theory](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~fpaugam/documents/enseignement/master-mathematical-physics.pdf), he writes the following in the introduction:

> Let us first illustrate this very general notion by the simple example of Newtonian mechanics in the plane. Let $M=[0,1]$ be the time parameter interval, and $C={\Bbb R}^2$ be the configuration plane. In this case a field is simply a function $x:M \to C$ that represents the motion of a particle in the plane. ...
>
> We will suppose given the additional datum of some starting and ending points $x_0,x_1 \in C$, and of the corresponding speed vectors $\vec{v}_0,\vec{v}_1$...
>
> We may identify the space of trajectories with the space of pairs $(x_0,\vec{v}_0)$ that are initial conditions for the corresponding differential equation. This space of pairs is the cotangent space $T^* C$ of the configuration space.
>
> note:the bar over the x should be a little arrow, and R should be in black-board font, as is usual for the space of real numbers - but I don't know the latex for this. I'll fix it if advised how.

On the face of it, it seems this should be the tangent bundle $TC$ rather than the cotangent bundle $T^*C$. So, why the choice of cotangent bundle here?

Comment: Yes, this is sloppy writing. If one is talking about velocitites, it's the tangent bundle. With momenta, it's the cotangent bundle (which has a canonical symplectic structure so that one can do Hamiltonian mechanics). In $\mathbb{R}^n$ one doesn't see much of a difference, which is probably the reason for the mixup.

Comment: Aren't "space of pairs (x 0 ,v 0 ¯ )" positions and not trajectories. Thus cotangent bundle.

Comment: As per Hans Lundmark. And further, the tangent space setup is the natural background for Lagrange mechanics, i.e., treating physics as a variational problem. One can always recommend V. I. Arnol'd: "Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics" for a comparative exposition of these formulations.

Comment: The cotangent bundle appears in a rather non trivial way into the picture, using the Legendre transform and what not. You should consult Arnol'd's book.

Comment: @Lutzl: So, tangent bundle for the Lagrangian perspective; and cotangent bundle for the Hamiltonian one; with Legendres transform to transform between the two pictures?

Comment: Yes, more or less. Newtonian mechanics is mostly descriptive (change in linear motion is proportional to force, and force is what changes linear motion) and allows to model the most situations. Lagrange mechanics gives a first principles formulation with fewer first principles for most of Newton mechanics. Hamiltionian mechanics is the most geometric, makes study of invariants easy and also quantization, but is restricted to conservative systems, which is fine for particles and rigid bodies, but complicated for elasticity and friction.